# How to run Cardano Wallet?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, cardano

I have installed cardano-wallet using [this documentation](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet). Everything is OK, Just I don't know how to run it so I can have interaction with it via node js:

```
const { WalletServer } = require('cardano-wallet-js');

let walletServer = WalletServer.init('http://127.0.0.1:1337/v2');
async function test() {
  let information = await walletServer.getNetworkInformation();
  console.log(information);
}
test()
```

Does's anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

According to IOHK documentation, prior to running a server you have to `run` a node:

```
cardano-node run \                                   
    --topology ~/cardano/config/mainnet-topology.json \
    --database-path ~/cardano/db/ \
    --socket-path ~/cardano/db/node.socket \
    --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \                
    --port 1337 \
    --config ~/cardano/config/mainnet-config.json
```

And after that call a `serve` command with appropriate flags:

```
cardano-wallet serve \                            
    --port 8090 \
    --mainnet \
    --database ~/cardano/wallets/db \
    --node-socket $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH
```

If you need more details, read my [medium post](https://medium.com/geekculture/cardano-911-wallet-command-line-interface-part-one-ad0ee5ac8509).

Answer (score 0):

you have to run cardano node in order query blockchain.
follow this article
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-wallet-js

you have to first download this file docker-compose.yml

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/master/docker-compose.yml
```

then run your node either testnet or mainnet by this command

```
NETWORK=testnet docker-compose up
```

then you can able to connect with blockchain
ref - https://github.com/tango-crypto/cardano-wallet-js